# Sequelize operations on read-only schema?

Tags: sequelize.js

The schema I wish to use is read-only to the user I will be using Sequelize with. Is there any way to tell Sequelize that it is not allowed to create/drop/alter tables or any other schema object? It is only permitted to insert/delete/update/select.

Currently if I follow the example and do:

```
sequelize.sync({force: false}).then(function() {
       return Video.create({
           path: filename
       }
});
```

I get back the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_TABLEACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: CREATE command denied to user 'nodeuser'@'localhost' for table 'video'
```

What is the correct way to do create operations and other related operations on a schema where we aren't permitted to modify its structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I missed the obvious. Just call:

```
Video.create({
    path: filename
});
```

Though just to be more complete:

```
Video.create({
    path: filename
}).then(function(entry) {
    // do something with the now persisted entry 
}).catch(function(error) {
    // handle any errors that may happen
});
```

The `sync()` function is only needed if you want Sequelize to sync your entity definition to the database. I had missed this, since the examples all seem to use it, until you start digging into the documentation.

Further documentation here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/